# How to ship a Sinatra application as a gem and deploy it?

Tags: deployment, rubygems, sinatra, rack

I have a sinatra application and packaged that [as a gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/tubemp). Its file-layout looks roughly like this:

```
├── bin
│   └── tubemp
├── lib
│  └── tubemp.rb
├── Gemfile
└── tubemp.gemspec
```

I can install and run it just fine. Calling `ruby lib/tubemp.rb` fires the app too, because Sinatra made it self-starting. `tubemp.rb`:

```
class Tubemp < Sinatra::Application
  get '/' do
    erb :index, :locals => { :title => "YouTube embeds without third party trackers." }
  end
end
```

The binary is really simple too. `bin/tubemp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "tubemp.rb"
Tubemp.run!
```

But now I want to deploy this as Rack-app. Or deploy it inside a Rack-app. At least it should run under Passenger on a production machine.

With a generic application it is as simple as adding a `config.ru` in the directory where the application lives. This file then, roughly, includes and calls `run Tubemp`. Pointing nginx or apache's passenger at the dir where this rackup file and the app lives, starts it.
This worked, up to the point where I made it a gem; because now I no longer have "a directory where the app lives", other then where `gem install tubemp` decides to place the files.

Do I need to create a `wrapper` application wich bundles the tubemp-gem and its dependencies? If so, how do I call the gem from a `rackup` file? Or am I going at this entirely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring [path-issues](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__the_applications_root_directory) for now, here is how [I solved it](https://github.com/berkes/tubemp-site):

The application bundled as gem, `tubemp`.

A `Gemfile` to install and include the gemified application:

```
gem 'tubemp'
```

A `config.ru` which runs the gemified application, called `Tubemp`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup' # To allow inclusion via the Bundle/Gemfile
require 'sinatra'       # Sinatra is required so we can call its "set"
require 'tubemp'        # And include the application

# Set the environment to :production on production
set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym

# And fire the application.
run Tubemp
```

These two files is all that is needed to make a new rack-application, which includes the
gemified Sinatra-app and as such are bootable trough e.g. nginx,
passenger or simply `rackup`.