# Deploy Sinatra app as gem to artifactory server

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems, sinatra, artifactory

I will be building a simple web-app in Sinatra, but Need to be able to run `build.cmd` and have it build a gem from the files, ship the gem to [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti) for deployment.

Could some one please advise me as I'm a little lost and I can't find any web-resources that will help me.

Please note, I'm doing this on a windows machine and it will be deployed to a virtual windows machine on a cloud, we have a chef server running which will be used to configure the VM enviroment.

Artifactory has Rubygems installed.

Would it be worth using [orca](https://github.com/andykent/orca)?

EDIT:
would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100398/how-to-ship-a-sinatra-application-as-a-gem-and-deploy-it) be of use to me?

Comment: I don't know what `build.cmd` is, but the "this" link should be what you need. Having said that, if the VM is just to run this, then I'd add it directly to the VM, no need to gemify it.

Comment: `build.cmd` is just a windows script file that would be used to start a build sequance.